# Cannot access default controller in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-deployment

Hello all am new to codeigniter I have developed the application and uploaded to server i can't access the default controller help me to solve it.This is my link

http://www.digitalmarketingbangalore.in/demobox/koooly

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.digitalmarketingbangalore.in/demobox/koooly';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'user';

$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;
$route['admin'] = 'admin/dashboard';
```

Controller: user

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class User extends CI_Controller {


            public function index()
            {
                    $this->load->view('login');
            }

}


?>
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|asset|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: what error getting ?

Comment: i think issue with .htacess. please check or edit post.

Comment: http://www.digitalmarketingbangalore.in/demobox/koooly/index.php/user/  used this its working

Comment: remove index.php in config.php and .htaccess set

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess add in below location

/demobox/koooly/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|asset|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and config/config.php
 change below

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.digitalmarketingbangalore.in/demobox/koooly';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: still the same 404 page not found

Comment: you remove index.php in config.php ??

Comment: also add .htaccess ??

Comment: $config['index_page'] = ''; change in config.php

Comment: yeah i have changed my config and updated htaccess code by your code

Answer (score 0):

Update your config to look like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.digitalmarketingbangalore.in/demobox/koooly/';
```